# "Pitch": the most intense state or stage of an event

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm after an expression.  It eludes me.

I want to express something to the effect of, "At the pinnacle of the war", or "in its most intense fully-fledged state".  But using the term "pitch"?  "Fever pitch" isn't quite right.  Do I have my neurological wires crossed, or is there actually a common expression on the tip of my tongue?

Comment: Could it be “peak” like at the peak of something

Comment: Reasonable research is expected to be shown (linked and attributed material), even where such research does not turn up the desired result. Here, just looking up "fever pitch" in a dictionary (eg [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fever-pitch)) or thesaurus gives quite a few synonyms. If you are sure 'fever' is included in the expression, looking up 'fever' in a collocations dictionary seems a good place to start.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - don forget they are e new user, CoC expects more experienced user to be nice, helpful and respectful. Close Voting is not going to help in any possible way.

Comment: @user067531 Don't forget that the whole aim of ELU, perhaps uniquely among Stack Exchange sites, is to build up a readily searchable, authoritative, scholarly  and credible repository of accepted English usage. Universities often don't accept first-time applicants; are they at fault for seeking to maintain standards by so doing? There are _helpful_ guidelines on how to ask a good question available to all who can be bothered to look.

Comment: Calling it a "pinnacle" is already an idiom (for a mountain peak) that could work. Perhaps also "at the *climax* of the war"; "at the war's *watershed*"; or "when the war was at a *fever pitch*". Maybe "The Battle of Midway was a *turning point* in the Pacific theater.

Comment: In what context or sentence do you want to use this word? I'm not sure whether you're looking for a noun like *pinnacle* or *pitch* or an adjective like *fully-fledged*.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin in any war-like situation or mass civil conflict that has reached its climax.  For example the current Hong Kong protest movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the idioms of **pitch**, **a pitched battle** would seem to fit your question:  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pitched+battle) an idiom

> any intense fight in which the combatants are fiercely engaged.

Originally describing place and scope of military battle, now **a pitched battle** can be applied to figurative battles in sports, politcs etc...

> Calgary won, 2-1, in overtime at Staples Center in a pitched battle
>   for eighth place in the Western Conference and now lead the Kings by
>   one point. Los Angeles Times Jan. 2015

and

> Hong Kong is facing another day of anti-government action after a
>   night of pitched battles at a top university. BBC Nov.  2019

Comment: I'm starting to think that I need to relax the question a bit to include other sayings not featuring pitch because the best candidate "pitched battle" wasn't quite what I had in mind even...  More something to the effect of "at it's highest intensity, we saw protesters and riot police exchanging projectiles".  But on a best answer basis, I'll give it to you.